# jquery fileinput getlocation before send

Tags: jquery

```
$("#upload-excel").fileinput({
    required: true,
    browseClass: "btn btn-secondary input-custom-query",
    browseIcon: "",
    removeClass: "btn btn-danger",
    removeLabel: "",
    removeIcon: "<i class='icon-trash-alt1'></i>",
    showUpload: true,
    uploadAsync: false,
    uploadUrl: $('#upload-excel').attr('data-route'),
    uploadExtraData:{
      '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    allowedFileExtensions: ['xls', 'xlsx'],
    maxFileSize: 264000
  }).on('filebatchuploadsuccess', function (event, data) {
    let result = data.response.data;
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      markup(result[i][0].a, result[i][0].b, result[i][0].c);
    }

    $('#modal_result').modal('show');
  }).on('filebatchuploaderror', function (event, data) {
    alert('Err!');
  });
```

I want to send location with uploadExtraData but geolocation is working async. How should i say wait getCurrentPosition before upload?

I want to get latitude and longitude information of user before every file upload.

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    });
  } else {
     latitude = 0;
     longitude = 0;
  }
```

Comment: Unless this is for a mobile app where the users moves around wouldn't it be possible to fetch the location on page load, or Init function. then simply append it every time?

If they do move around maybe you can set a timeout function to prefetch it every 1-2min

Comment: @Cees yes i thought it for mobile users. Fetching location in every 1-2 min is a good idea, thank you.

Comment: Why not trigger it in the `filepreajax` callback?  https://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-events#filepreajax

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```
$("#upload-excel").fileinput({
  required: true,
  browseClass: "btn btn-secondary input-custom-query",
  browseIcon: "",
  removeClass: "btn btn-danger",
  removeLabel: "",
  removeIcon: "<i class='icon-trash-alt1'></i>",
  showUpload: true,
  uploadAsync: false,
  uploadUrl: $('#upload-excel').attr('data-route'),
  uploadExtraData: {
    '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  },
  allowedFileExtensions: ['xls', 'xlsx'],
  maxFileSize: 264000
})
.on('filepreajax', function(event, previewId, index){
  var coords = {
    latitude: 0, 
    longitude: 0
  };
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      coords = position.coords;
    });
  }
  var extraData = $(this).data('fileinput').uploadExtraData;
  $.extend(extraData, coords);
  $(this).fileinput("uploadExtraData", extraData);
})
.on('filebatchuploadsuccess', function(event, data) {
  let result = data.response.data;
  for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    markup(result[i][0].a, result[i][0].b, result[i][0].c);
  }

  $('#modal_result').modal('show');
})
.on('filebatchuploaderror', function(event, data) {
  alert('Err!');
});
```

This is completely untested as I do not use this plugin. I am assuming you are using the Bootstrap FileInput.

The other option would be to collect this data inside a function for `uploadExtraData`. An example would be:

```
uploadExtraData: function (previewId, index) {
  var obj = {
    '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    'latitude': 0, 
    'longitude': 0
  };
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      obj.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      obj.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    });
  }
  return obj;
}
```

The crux of this, mobile or not, is that the User will need to allow the browser to disclose the location. When I test here: https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation I am prompted to Block or Allow revealing my Location in FireFox. This means when you trigger this bit of code, if it is in the middle of an operation that the User can't Allow the activity or adjust the preference, it might fail.